# SQL query to multiple servers fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, multiserver

I try to run this query against multiple registered SQL Servers with SSMS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(volume_mount_point), 
    total_bytes / 1048576 AS Size_in_MB, 
    available_bytes / 1048576 AS Free_in_MB,
    (SELECT ROUND(CAST(available_bytes / 1048576 * 1.0 as FLOAT) / CAST(total_bytes / 1048576 * 1.0 AS FLOAT) * 100, 2)) AS FreePercentage
FROM 
    sys.master_files AS f 
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id)
GROUP BY
    volume_mount_point, total_bytes / 1048576, available_bytes / 1048576  
ORDER BY 
    4
```

Some of the servers have SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM product level which doesn't know "sys.dm_os_volume_stats" and whole query crashes reporting:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'sys.dm_os_volume_stats'.

I tried to add a condition before the main SELECT, but it doesn't work:

```
  DECLARE @ProductLevel varchar(128)  
  SET @ProductLevel = CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductLevel'))
  IF @ProductLevel not like 'RTM'
    BEGIN...
```

I also tried to separate results by this documentation
[To change the multiserver results options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/execute-statements-against-multiple-servers-simultaneously?view=sql-server-2017#to-change-the-multiserver-results-options)

> To change the multiserver results options In Management Studio, on the
>   Tools menu, click Options.
>
> Expand Query Results, expand SQL Server, and then click Multiserver
>   Results.
>
> On the Multiserver Results page, specify the option settings that you
>   want, and then click OK.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IF` condition won't be evaluated if the DMV doesn't exist because the entire batch fails at compilation time so the `IF` statement is never executed.

One workaround is to wrap the query in conditional dynamic SQL:

```
IF CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(20)),4) AS int) > 10 OR 
    (CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(20)),4) AS int) = 10
     AND CAST(PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(20)),3) AS int) = 5
     AND SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') <> 'RTM')
BEGIN
EXEC sp_executesql N'
SELECT DISTINCT(volume_mount_point), 
    total_bytes / 1048576 AS Size_in_MB, 
    available_bytes / 1048576 AS Free_in_MB,
    (SELECT ROUND(CAST(available_bytes / 1048576 * 1.0 as FLOAT) / CAST(total_bytes / 1048576 * 1.0 AS FLOAT) * 100, 2)) AS FreePercentage
FROM 
    sys.master_files AS f 
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.file_id)
GROUP BY
    volume_mount_point, total_bytes / 1048576, available_bytes / 1048576  
ORDER BY 
    4;
'
END;
```

Comment: I've just tried to run your query against two test servers (both non RTM) and it returned only this:

"server1\DB1(login): (4 row(s) affected)"

Comment: @JosefB., forgot to include the product level check too so I added it.

Comment: Now I understand where you are aiming! I just need to adjust your query a little bit. The Product version of SQL2008 R2 RTM is 10.50.1600.1 and Product version of SQL2008 R2 SP2 is 10.50.4042.0, where the sys.dm_os_volume_stats is integrated. So the condition "ProductVersion >= 11" cannot be met with a lot of SQL servers in my enviroment, but anyway your query will help me a lot. I'll come back as I get fully working query. Thank you!

Comment: @JosefB., sorry I didn't have a SQL 2008 R2 RTM instance handy to test. I tweaked the query with a condition I think will work.

Comment: at first - please don't apologize - I'm happy you are helping me. Second thing, I simplified the condition to this "IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE name = 'dm_os_volume_stats'))". Third thing - it is not necesary to use executing it as **stored procedure** but still I have to set parameter for Tools\Multiserver results\Merge results to False